# Unable to access TeamCity when running under port 80

Tags: ubuntu, teamcity

After completing a fresh install of TeamCity and attempting to run TeamCity on a different port than the default (8111) using the below configuration in the `<TeamCity Directory>/conf/server.xml`:

```
<!-- Run TeamCity on port 80 (localhost) -->
<Connector port="80" protocol=...></Connector>
```

I am unable to access TeamCity on localhost. Running `curl` yields the following results:

```
$ curl localhost
Failed to connect to localhost on port 80: Connection Refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because port `80` is a privileged port, root access must be given during TeamCity's start up for it to be able to run on port `80`.

`$ sudo <TeamCity Dir>/bin/runAll.sh start`